# Making a adjacency list of pairs

Tags: c++, data-structures

I am taking input from a file in following form :

3

0 1

0 2

1 0

1 2

2 0

2 1

Here 3 is unique number of numbers in the list i.e., 0,1,2.

I have successfully made a adjacency list of the list.
O/P :

0 -> 1 2

1 -> 0 2

2 -> 0 1

Using the following code

```
if (input.is_open())
{
    cout << "File is Open. \n";
    input >> totalnode;

    pair<pair<int,int>, pair<int,int>> a;
    vector<list<int>>adjlist(totalnode);
    while (input >> node1 >> node2)
    {
        adjlist[node1].push_back(node2);
    }
    vector<list<int>>::iterator i;
    int c = 0;
    for ( i = adjlist.begin(); i != adjlist.end(); ++i)
    {
        cout << c << " -> ";
        list<int> li = *i;
        list<int>::iterator iter; 
        for ( iter = li.begin(); iter != li.end(); ++iter)
        {
            cout << *iter << " ";
        }
        cout << "\n";
        c++;
    }
```

Now I wish to make adjacency list of pairs.

Example :

0,1 -> (0,2) (1,0) (1,2) (2,0) (2,1)

0,2 -> (0,1) (1,0) (1,2) (2,0) (2,1)

1,0 -> (0,1) (0,2) (1,2) (2,0) (2,1)

I think, I should use this,

```
vector<pair<int, int>> asd;
```

or

```
vector<list<pair<int,int>>> asd;
```

How do I compare pairs? Honestly I have no idea, how to achieve this.

Comment: The default comparison overload for `std::pair` should work. No extra effort is needed.

Comment: Thanks for help did it!

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the requirement. As rightly said by [Sam](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3943312/sam-varshavchik), there is default comparison overload which first compares the `first` field. If that is same, then it compares the `second` field.

If that's what you want, then just use it directly.

Otherwise, Overload comparison operator. I think in your case, you don't need it.

In your case, what you should do is maintain a `map`.

```
map<pair<int, int>, vector< pair<int, int> > > asd;
```

and directly use `pair` as key for the map.

Comment: Thanks for help! I did it!